# TYPO3 tt_news - adding images in prev/next links

Tags: typo3, tt-news

Do anyone know how to add into tt_news textual previous and next links the images (from news item)? Is it possible?

Best regards,

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

You could change the stdWrap of these links

```
plugin.tt_news {
  displaySingle {
    prevLink_stdWrap.wrap = |<img src="prev.jpg">
    nextLink_stdWrap.wrap = |<img src="next.jpg">
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want... I mean the images from the tt_news item